# Why are there 10 times more questions on English openings than on Reti opening?

Tags: discussion, tags

I am not sure if this questions will be more suitable for Chess Beta or Chess Meta. To play safe, I am asking it here:

At this moment, there are 23 questions tagged as [english-opening](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english-opening) and only 2 questions tagged as [reti-opening](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reti-opening).

Why there are 10 times more questions on English openings than on Reti opening? To me, the popularity of these two openings is almost equal. Why do people have far less questions on Reti than on English then? Is it because Reti is easier?

Answer (score 4):

One possible reason could be that people are familiar with the *name* English opening, but not so with Reti. After all, according to Wikipedia, 1. Nf3 is the [Zukertort opening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zukertort_Opening). Note that this definition disagrees with the current tag wiki excerpt for [reti-opening](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reti-opening).

Again, if you follow Wikipedia, it doesn't become a proper Reti opening until after 1... d5 2. c4. [Chessgames.com](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/explorer?node=77705&move=2&moves=Nf3.d5&nodes=74.77705) has a little over 5k games with those moves, while 1. c4 is played [64k times](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/explorer). 64 / 5 is not far off from the 23 / 2 ratio in tag usage.

An example question which currently does not have the Reti tag, maybe because people are following the Wikipedia definition, is [good responses to 1. Nf3](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/9705/7297).

Comment: Thank you for your prompt and detailed answer! It seeems they do not have a tag called "Zukertort opening" as well.

Comment: According to Chessgames.com, 1. Nf3 is played 82k times and 1. c4 64k times. If we call 1. Nf3 a reti opening (as is defined in the tag) it should have more questions under this tag.

Comment: Yes, 1. Nf3 is played more often (but can easily transpose into 1. e4 or 1. d4 openings). What I'm trying to say is that the tag excerpt might be wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Reti is not a main system like English or the QGD, and also 1. Nf3 is not always associated with Reti or considered as a system on its own. If you want to prepare for 1.Nf3 you need to consider both English and QGD literature.